# In angular 2 How do I do a jsonp.request and where do I import jsonp from

Tags: angular

In angular 2 How do I do a jsonp.request and where do I import jsonp from?

I'm using the latest angular2 libraries.

This Is how I used to do it 6 months ago before I upgraded:

```
  this.jsonp.request(url, config).subscribe(response => {
     this.blogArticles = response._body.response.posts;
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

> ```
> import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
> import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
> import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
> import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
>
> import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
>
> @NgModule({
>   imports: [
>     BrowserModule,
>     FormsModule,
>     HttpModule,
>     JsonpModule
>   ],
>   declarations: [ AppComponent ],
>   bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
> })
> export class AppModule { }
> ```

```
class MyComponent { 
  constructor(private jsonp:Jsonp) {}

  someMethod() {
    this.jsonp.get(url).subscribe(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've now setup my modules. Just how do I import it in the component?

Comment: I updated my answer. The link contains a nice full example.

Answer (score 0):

You can import JsonpModule from @angular/http like this-

```
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [    BrowserModule,    FormsModule,    HttpModule,    JsonpModule ],
...
```

And in component, use it like this-

```
constructor(private jsonp:Jsonp) {}
...
this.jsonp.get(url).subscribe(...);
...
```